# What i adjust for android login into RESTful api in this conditions?

Tags: android, django, authentication

I'm in conditions follows

1. I have RESTful API using Django (DJango-rest-auth/You might see it http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
2. I post parameters in json type like

{

```
"username": "blahblah",

"email": "~~~blah@blah~.com",

"password1": "blahblah",

"password2": "blahblah"
```

}

and then I receive

```
HTTP 200 OK
  Allow: POST, OPTIONS
  Content-Type: application/json
  Vary: Accept

  {
    "key": "99defb355414133f00ad88e15771e3a8b43e71f"
}
```

But i can't understand How to use this.

django-rest-auth says

```
  {
    "name": "Login",
    "description": "Check the credentials and return the REST Token\nif the credentials are valid and authenticated.\nCalls Django Auth login method to register User ID\nin Django session framework\n\nAccept the following POST parameters: username, password\nReturn the REST Framework Token Object's key.",
    "renders": [
        "application/json",
        "text/html"
    ],
```

I think this means i use that "key" for authentication, for example,

If i use retrofit2, i post id and password to my rest url, and receive key value from rest url. Then use key on sharedpreference to maintain user login.

Is it right way?

Im very new bie,

please give me some hints what i learn or what should i do.

What i want most is it : 1.login from android 2.to maintain login on android to use other contents which is in my restful api service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the http `Authorization` header in yours requests:

in android try:

```
urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Token " + your_token);
```